# git auth fails after eclipse update 2021-03

Tags: git, eclipse, ssh, bitbucket, egit

After the recent eclipse update 2021-03 all bitbucket.org repositories can't pull/push anymore:

```
Pulling 1 repository
   git@bitbucket.org:Acountxxx/Repoxxx.git: Cannot log in at bitbucket.org:22
   git@bitbucket.org:Acountxxx/Repoxxx.git: Cannot log in at bitbucket.org:22
```

I tried to clone the repositories in a fresh workspace, also using ssh:

URI: ssh://bitbucket.org/REPOxxxx.git
Host: bitbucket.org
Repository Path: REPOxxxxx.git
Protocol: ssh
Port: blank
User: blank
Password: blank

Running into the same exception:

```
ssh://bitbucket.org:Acountxxx/Repoxxx.git: Cannot log in at bitbucket.org:22
```

The CMD `git pull` or `git push` still work fine.

Did anyone have the same issue and found a solution?

**Environment:** 
Windows 10 
git version 2.30.1.windows.1 
Eclipse 2021-03
EGit: 5.11.0.202103091610-r

**EDIT**: Also interesting, other repositories e.g. from github still work fine. This behavior is the same for private and public repositories on bitbucket.

Comment: Which EGit/JGit version? Is your private key configured in the preferences in _General > Network Connections > SSH2_? Or is the environment variable `GIT_SSH` set? Does a fresh workspace work?

Comment: Added some more infos.
GIT_SSH is not set but it was also not set pre update when the repositories were working. Fresh workspace does also not work.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer, but your detailed self-answer is probably more helpful for others and should therefore be shown at the top.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the information of [howlger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6505250/howlger) about [Known_problems](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.11#Known_problems) -> [Bug 572056 - Cannot work with Bitbucket after Eclipse update](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572056) I did the following workaround which solved the issue.

Open CMD and run:

```
ssh-keygen -t ed25519
```

This created a new key: *C:/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519*

Login to bitbucket and add content of the public key file (*C:/Users/USER/.ssh/id_ed25519.pub*) as new key:
https://bitbucket.org/account/settings/ssh-keys/

Configure this key in the eclipse preferences:

[image]

Afterwards pulling and pushing works again. A little research showed that ed25519 is even more secure and faster then default RSA algorithm, so a very nice solution actually.

Answer (score 4):

You probably face the following known issue of EGit/JGit 5.11, for which there are two workarounds (see [New and Noteworthy of EGit 5.11](https://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/New_and_Noteworthy/5.11#Known_problems)):

> [Bug 572056](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=572056): Connecting to **bitbucket.org** with an **RSA** key:
> the SSH library used has changed in JGit from Apache MINA sshd 2.4.0
> to 2.6.0. sshd 2.6.0 by default does public-key authentication for RSA
> keys using the *rsa-sha2-512* signature algorithm only. Servers that
> do not understand that mechanism but only the older *ssh-rsa*
> signature algorithm will then refuse the log-in.
>
> - Known affected git servers: bitbucket.org, AWS Code Commit
> - Work-arounds:
>
>   - Use an **ed25519** key.
>   - Use an external SSH via environment variable **`GIT_SSH`**.